# How do I change the file print setting on Excel to use VBA to print several pages when printing the workbook

Tags: excel, printing, excel-2007, vba

I would like to change the file print setting in Excel to go directly to VBA and print some of the 26 worksheets while printing the workbook.  Most of the active worksheets should print, but a few of the worksheets should not print.  The workbook is a template and the number of active and printed worksheets will change with each new workbook created.  Lastly, should the VBA code go in the "ThisWorkbook" section?

Comment: `Lastly, should the VBA code go in the "ThisWorkbook" section? ` Yes, it will go into `Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)` Try googling and then show the code that you tried and we will then take it from there?

Comment: This seems to work, but it automatically prints.  Is there a way to change the number of sheets printed using the existing print screen (this way the user could print a PDF copy?Public Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Sheets("Summary").Select
Call Unlock_Sheet
ActiveSheet.Visible = False
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut
Sheets("Summary").Visible = True
Call Lock_Sheet
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like

```
Sub PrintSheets ()
Dim Wks1 as Worksheet: set Wks1=Sheets("SheetName1")
Wks1.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
'[...] and so on with your sheets
```

Where the no of copies can be changed
To fully automatize the code I usualy create a new sheet called "Macro keys" where I store the sheets' name and copy count (i.e. A1= "SheetName1", B1="5" , A2="SheetName2", B2="10"). Thus:

```
Sub PrintSheets ()
Dim MacroKeys as Worksheet: Set MacroKeys = Sheets("Macrokeys")
SheetName1 = Macrokeys.Range("A1").Value
SheetName1_CopyCount = Macrokeys.Range("B1").Value
Sheet(SheetName1 ).PrintOut Copies:= SheetName1_CopyCount, Collate:=True
'[...] and so on with your sheets
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!