# Getting Rid of Unwanted Pagebreaks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add page breaks to an excel sheet, but am having trouble getting the page breaks to go where I want them, or more accurately, to not go where I don't want them.

I want the code to insert a page break to the left of column "x," with x being a previously defined variable (7 in this case). I can get the page break at column x to work, but another page break (a dashed blue line) keeps showing up left of column 6, and another one (a solid blue line) left of column 8.

The method that I am using to add the page breaks is this:

```
Worksheets("BASE 2").VPageBreaks.Add Before:=Worksheets("BASE 2").Columns(x)
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
```

If I only run the `ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview` section, the two incorrect page breaks (before columns 6 and 8) still show up, and the same thing happens when I run the code with only the `Worksheets("BASE 2").VPageBreaks.Add Before:=Worksheets("BASE 2").Columns(x)` section.

If anyone has any insight as to why this may be happening, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This is probably due to the print setup, you may need to change it to force the layout you want.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Do you mean a setting within excel itself? This macro is going to have to run on multiple computers, and I would rather the settings not have to be changed on every computer. Is there a way to edit the page break settings with VBA?

Comment: Yes and yes,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158209/how-do-i-change-the-file-print-setting-on-excel-to-use-vba-to-print-several-page) may get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the future that has a similar problem.

The reason that excel was adding in the extra dashed page break was that the section I was trying to print was too large to print on one sheet. I was originally trying to print a section with a total column width of 300 zoomed at 50% using `Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.Zoom = 50`.

To fix the problem, I backed off the column width to 290 and the zoom to 40 and the dashed blue line stopped showing up.